# How can I get a property's object instance through a parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, instance-variables

How can I get a property's object instance through a parameter in C#? I'm not sure if it's called a variable instance, but here's what I meant:

In the usual case, when we do this, we get the value of the variable in C#:

```
void performOperation(ref Object property) {
   //here, property is a reference of whatever was passed into the variable
}

Pet myPet = Pet();
myPet.name = "Kitty";
performOperation(myPet.name);   //Here, what performOperation() will get is a string
```

What I hope to achieve, is to get the object from the property of the class, like say:

```
void performOperation(ref Object property) {
   //so, what I hope to achieve is something like this:

   //Ideally, I can get the Pet object instance from the property (myPet.name) that was passed in from the driver class
   (property.instance().GetType()) petObject = (property.instnace().GetType())property.instance();  

    //The usual case where property is whatever that was passed in. This case, since myPet.name is a string, this should be casted as a string
   (property.GetType()) petName = property;   
}

Pet myPet = Pet();
myPet.name = "Kitty";
performOperation(myPet.name);   //In this case, performOperation() should be able to know myPet from the property that was passed in
```

The `instance()` is just a dummy method to demonstrate that I want to get the property's instance object. I am very new to C#. This is conceptually what I wish to achieve but I am not sure how I could do so in C#. I looked through the Reflection API but I'm still not very sure what I should use to do this.

So, how can I get a property's object instance through a parameter in C#?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will have to pass the object as well as the property into `performOperation`.

Comment: So there is no where that I can get the property's object instance from just the property itself?

Comment: I don't think so, at least not the way you've accessed the property in your example.

Comment: I see. And yea, the way I accessed the property in my example is merely an illustration of my intetnion because I'm not sure how I should go about do so. I'm also somewhat new to C#'s syntax. Thanks. :)

Comment: If you get the `PropertyInfo` for that property. You can then use the [`DeclaringType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx) to get the **class** that declares the member, but it doesn't look like you can get the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a property value to a method, for example:

```
SomeMethod(obj.TheProperty);
```

Then it is implemented as:

```
SomeType foo = obj.TheProperty;
SomeMethod(foo);
```

You ***cannot*** get the parent object from that, basically. You would need to pass that separately, for example:

```
SomeMethod(obj, obj.TheProperty);
```

Additionally, keep in mind that a value can be part of *any number* of objects. A string instance could be used in zero, one, or "many" objects. What you ask is fundamentally not possible.